# How do we add multiple keys and values to a google drive file using apps script console?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api

we used a code to add a key and value to a specific file in google drive using apps script console.

```gs
function addCustomProperty(fileId) 
{ 
   var fileId="************c3Rhc*******";
    var property =  
                 {
                    key: 'Version8',
                    value: 'PDF2026', 
                    visibility: 'PUBLIC' 
                  }; 
  Drive.Properties.insert(property, fileId);
  Logger.log(fileId);
  Logger.log(property);
}
```

After executing above given code in apps script console,
key and value added successfully to a file in google drive. Now how do we add multiple keys and values to the same file using the code given above. Any solution to this.

Comment: The code given above only adds a predefined property. So obviously you cannot just use the code given. Have you tried passing in the property you want to set?

Comment: my point is we are adding a key and a value using the above code, now we need multipe keys and values to add, i had multiple keys and values. how can i insert them. {key:"ay",value:"533"},
{key:'kiy',value:'33'},
{key:'iy',value:'33'},
{key:'iy',value:'3'},
{key:'kiy',value:'35'},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All methods in Google drive api are singiular

```
Drive.Properties.insert(property, fileId);
```

would insert a single property onto a file.

If you wish to insert more than one property then you will need to run the command multiple times

```
var property =  
             {
                key: 'Version8',
                value: 'PDF2026', 
                visibility: 'PUBLIC' 
              }; 

var property2 =  
             {
                key: 'Version1',
                value: 'PDF202', 
                visibility: 'PUBLIC' 
              }; 

Drive.Properties.insert(property, fileId);
Drive.Properties.insert(property2, fileId);
```

Comment: thank you for suggestion. i will implement this and let you know

Comment: Woman but your welcome .   Please remember to accept the answer if it helped you.